# finding f with the given information, antiderivatives?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Find $f$.
$$f''(t)=3/\sqrt{t}$$
$$f(4)=12$$
$$f'(4)=5$$
I'm not quite sure how I am supposed to find $f$ with this information.

Comment: Here, $f''$ is a power function, i.e., it has the form $a t^b$ for some constants $a, b$. How do you compute the antiderivative of a power function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Integrate $f''$ to find $f'$ up to an additive constant.

Then use the fact that you are told $f'(4)=5$ to find the specific additive constant.

Then, repeat the process: integrate this specific $f'$ to find $f$ up to another additive constant.

Finally, use the fact that you are told $f(4)=12$ to find this additive constant.

As an example, if you know $f(x)= 5x^2+C$, and you know $f(1) = 3$, then $5(1)^2+C=3$, so $C =-2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{d[f'(t)]}{dt}=3t^{-\frac12}$$

$$\implies d[f'(t)]=3t^{-\frac12}dt$$

Integrating either sides $$f'(t)=3\frac{t^{\frac12}}{\frac12}+K=6t^{\frac12}+K$$ where $K$ is an arbitrary constant  and as $\int x^m\ dx=\dfrac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}+K$ for $m+1\ne0$

$$5=f'(4)=6\cdot4^{\frac12}+K\implies K=?$$

Can you take it from here?